# Is c parameter or constant (random variable X with given density)

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image]

problem: is **c** constant or parameter

solution for this is to

$ \int_{1}^{2} cx^2 dx = \frac{7c}{3} $

$ \int_{2}^{3} cx dx = \frac{5c}{2} $

Until now I understand what is going on; next (I am looking at solution)

$ \frac{7c}{3} = A $

$ \frac{5c}{2} = 1 - A $ <- this is what I dont understand

next I solve the equations and get $ c = \frac{6}{29} $ and solution for the problem is "c is constant".

Another thing that I dont understand is why is c constant and not parameter?

---

Picture of original problem; language Slovak, ignore the pen part, its $ cx $

[image]

exact translation line by line:

2.1.35 Random variable X has density

$ f(x) ... $

a) Find out that, **c** is either parameter or constant.

Comment: MathJax is really easy, everything between $\$$ signs gets rendered as if it where mathematical expressions in $\LaTeX$. So for instance $\$$ \sqrt{4} $\$$ gives $ \sqrt{4} $.

Comment: The question makes almost no sense. There must be a lot of the problem statement that you have omitted here and are expecting readers to guess. It looks like you're for some reason attempting to find a $c$ such that $\int f=1$, but it is extremely unclear what you mean by your distinction between "constant" and "parameter".

Comment: @Henning Makholm exactly! I dont understand either, in the book where I got the problem from it states: (the original) $ f(x) = cx^2 ... $ and a) Determine if **c** is constant or defined constant (rough translation). b) calculate $ P(X>2) $

Comment: "Determine if c is constant or defined constant" ?? Perhaps try the original version and somebody else will translate?

Comment: @Pedro thank you I will edit question so it looks nice.

Comment: @did defined* certain

Comment: Questions that ask for help in understanding what a homework exercise is asking for should contain an _exact quote_ of the _entire_ problem statement, clearly delimited from _your_ text, and preferably with a reference to the book you find the problem in.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Its not homework, I have solution to it I am studying for test and this problem is one that I can not solve myself. I edited question + added picture of original problem.

Comment: OK, voted to reopen. (My advice above was not restricted to "homework", but applies equally to exam questions, training problems, contest problems, etc.)

Comment: I really do not understand why question got closed so quick, why didn't you all wait at least until I edit, add some context whatever you needed from me. In SO I never vote for close until OP is not communicating... this is sad.

Comment: What is sad? Question will get reopened shortly. Or should it be sad that math.SE is or is not following your usage of SO?

Comment: #did second one, I haven't experienced reopening questions so quick on SO (probably because of amount of questions). Original Post got judged too quickly for me to respond that what is sad. In case there is quick re-opening on math.SE who cares... thanks for input.

Comment: I voted to reopen too. The question makes a bit more sense now (for example, originally it was totally unclear what this had to do with the tag "random variables"). A possible interpretation of the terminology is this: Is the integral equal to 1 for all values of c? In that case, this is a family of probability distributions, with c as a "parameter". But if there's only one value of c which makes the integral equal to 1, then c must have exactly that value, so it's a "constant".

Comment: Original post was judged exactly right (as being bad), then you responded, then it was *quickly* reopened. Nothing sad here. But something sad, if one insists, is that you felt entitled to declare that something was going wrong while being a newcomer and having spent probably zero minutes to get some information about the ways of the site. Insert here comparisons with arriving at somebody's house, and so on. (Unrelated (or is it?): #name does nothing but @name works.)

Comment: Yes, # typo... I simply don't c-vote when OP is present and communicating. I understand where you are going with the comments above, discussion about it is not needed problem is solved.

Comment: Second comment not addressed correctly to the user it is meant to be addressed to. Let me suggest you get acquainted with this @ system (is it not enforced on SO?).

Comment: @did thank you for suggestion. You seem smart enough to know that my comment(s) was(ere) meant for you, other than annoying notification for others I don't see any point in at-ing. No, noone is enforcing anything in whole SE network.

Comment: Hooray! You finally got the principle of the @ thing... Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is asking whether you can get different probability distributions by choosing different values of $c$. If you can, then $c$ would be a "parameter". However, in this case, there is only one value of $c$ that makes $f$ be a probability distribution at all (because the total probability has to be $1$), so it is not a parameter, but must have a constant value.

As for "$1-A$" in the model solution, that (together with the previous line) is just a roundabout way of stating the equation
$$ \frac73c + \frac52c = 1 $$
saying that the total probability must be $1$. I can't see that you get anything except obfuscation out of introducing the name $A$ for $\frac73c$.

Comment: I have solutions for most of the problems in my book so I learn by inspecting etc. In this case yes A is kind of obfuscation, **I didn't catch that**, If I would I wouldn't even ask on math.SE. I feel stupid (facepalm). Thank you very much.